# mysql, a column after update it get the null value, how can dont allow null in insert and update

Tags: mysql

In this table i want the title column to not allow null(not be blank) in inserting or update the row.... the user should 100% insert some value for it in order the row to be generated.

```
    create table tab(id int not null auto_increment
                 primary key,
                 title varchar(255) not null );
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the table created.

now i do insert:

insert into tab (`id`,`title`) value (1, 'title1');  .....true

insert into tab (`id`) value (2);.........................true ----- this should not be null.

```
mysql> select * from tab;
+----+--------+
| id | title  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | title1 |
|  2 |        |
+----+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Null or empty string? Probably you should remove default value

Comment: How i can make one column of table to be not null, when the user inserts data use 100% should inter value for that column of table if not it just give the error and rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `NOT NULL` constraint for column `title` and remove that `default ''`.

Cause that `default ''` is inserting a default empty string to title column whenever you don't supply a value for title column in `insert`.

so, if you have your schema as below with insert values

```
create table tab(id int not null auto_increment
                 primary key,
                 title varchar(255) not null default '');

insert into tab(title) values('aaaaa'),('mmmmmm'),('');
```

Then try the below query, it will return 0 rows. So essentially, you don't have a `NULL` value in `title` column but rather a `EMPTY STRING`.

```
select * from tab where title is null
```

Your schema should look like below,

```
create table tab(id int not null auto_increment
                 primary key,
                 title varchar(255) not null );
```

See a demo fiddle, if you want to examine further http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5acf/3

Comment: create table tab(id int not null auto_increment
                 primary key,
                 title varchar(255) not null ); 
--------i create such table and then i insert value(insert into tab (`id`) value (1); now the value one been inserted when the title is null(no value ) this should run query false but it run true

Comment: @abas_rafiq, that's not possible. did you tried? What you have posted as comment .. if you try it will throw an error because of NOT NULL constraint. Use that fiddle link and try what you commented. See how it fails.

Comment: please check my question again it's geting the null value i my self is kinda surprized... where i am doing mistak

Comment: ya i can not keep the ID - null it's about title secound column

Comment: @abas_rafiq, try reading SQL. You are not getting my point. In your show table both ID/title have default NULL which is impossible. Whatever, you tried (per post) try the same here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5acf/3. You will find that there is some issue with your mysql configuration and it's not the issue with query.

Comment: @abas_rafiq, see this fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30600a/2 to prove that what you are saying (per your post) can't be correct. don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.